# WCF Inherit contracts and callback contract

Tags: wcf

I have a test project that test the Inherit contracts and callback contract.

**Update 1** : I updated all of the topic with interfaces implamantations

By reading this article: http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Service-Contracts/Contract-Inheritance/#part-16

This is possibol but when i try it, it fails.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost Service_IServer = new ServiceHost(new ServiceImplemantation(), new Uri(@"net.tcp://localhost:8080/"));
            Service_IServer.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), "Service");
            Service_IServer.Open();
            ServiceHost Service_I_IP = new ServiceHost(new IPImplemantation(), new Uri(@"net.tcp://localhost:8080/"));
            Service_I_IP.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(I_IP), new NetTcpBinding(), "Service");
            Service_I_IP.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface I_IP
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetIP();
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService : I_IP
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ImTheServer_Print();
    }
    //
    //
    //
    //
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class IPImplemantation : I_IP
    {
        public string GetIP()
        {
            return "1.2.3.4";
        }
    }
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ServiceImplemantation : IPImplemantation, IService
    {
        public void ImTheServer_Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ImTheServer_Print");
        }
    }
```

**The error:**

The ChannelDispatcher at 'net.tcp://localhost:8080/Service' with contract(s) '"I_IP"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.

Comment: I think you have the answer right in the exception: "interface type is not the target of the ServiceContractAttribute's CallbackContract". GetIP is defined on I_IP, while CallbackContract references IServerCallback. Perhaps inheriting service methods is not supported? just a hunch...

Comment: by my google seartch, it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957116/wcf-contract-inherited-contracts

Comment: And what about your service / callback implementation? Does it also implements I_IP?

Comment: No,there is implementation to each of the contracts and the service / callback implementation inherit from the I_IP implementation .I wrote my project by this guid : http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Service-Contracts/Contract-Inheritance/#part-16

Comment: The post you pointed on http://stackoverflow.com/users/1413320/sergey you have to have implemented interface. Finaly, your callback should have this method available in amy way

Comment: service / callback implementations inherits the I_IP implementation that have the Get_IP method.

Comment: Can you try explicitly implement it? May be when your service/ callback casted to i_ip,  it does not work, since they does not "inherited" (implement) the interface?

Comment: I cant becouse I get this exception: The ChannelDispatcher at 'net.tcp://localhost:8080/Service' with contract(s) '"I_IP"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.

Comment: Sorry, dont have other input. May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252791/how-to-solve-the-channeldispatcher-is-unable-to-open-its-ichannellistener-erro

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you decorate it as `OneWay`.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void GetIP();
```

Comment: OperationBehavior is for class only, not interface. and my GetIP returns the IP. sory I missed it. OperationBehaviorAttribute can only go on the service class, it cannot be put on the ServiceContract interface. Method 'GetIP' on type 'I_IP' violates this.

Comment: i removed `operationbehavior`.

Comment: @StavAlfi callbacks can't return anything by design.